# Coq Set Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, coq

I have proven many Theorems starting from Real axioms, now I want to define Naturals as a subset of Reals and reuse all proven theorems. How can it be done? Here is an artificial MRE that would compile using proper coq design practices:

```
01  (* CReal Definitions *)
02  Parameter CReal: Set.
03  Parameter creal_add : CReal -> CReal -> CReal.
04  Axiom creal_comm: forall x y:CReal, creal_add x y = creal_add y x.
05   
06  (* CNat Definitions *)
07  Parameter CNat: Set.
08  Theorem cnat_comm: forall x y:CNat, creal_add x y = creal_add y x.
09  Proof. exact creal_comm. Qed. (* Should be OK after subclassing *)
```

Now it complains about O being CReal instead of CNat, thus it would be great if x were interpreted polymorphically as a CReal to be able to compare agains other CReals and apply over them CReal Theorems and Axioms in a pretty and non convoluted manner.

**EDIT**:

To make clearer what I want, here is code that should not compile after proper subclassing:

```
11  (* CNat Positive *)
12  Parameter O : CReal.
13  Parameter cnat_succ : CNat -> CNat.
14  Axiom cnat_positive: forall (x : CNat), ~cnat_succ x=O.
15
16  (* CReal Wrong Theorem *)
17  Theorem creal_positive: forall x:CReal, ~cnat_succ x=O. (*Crash*)
18  Proof. exact cnat_positive. Qed. (*Also Crash*)
```

The reason why lines 17 and 18 should crash is that 17 uses cnat_succ over a CReal, but cnat_succ is only defined for subclass CNat, and in 18 uses a CNat axiom, which should not be visible by superclass CReal. So, superclass Axioms and Theorems should be visible for and applicable by subclass, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out a solution using Typeclasses. Here is an extension of Naturals using Integers, which makes more sense than extending Reals using Naturals, the ones are somehow less specialized (require less axioms) than the former:

```
01  (* Import Setoid for smart rewriting *)
02  Require Import Setoid.
03  
04  
05  (* -------------------------------------------------- *)
06  (* CNat Class *)
07  
08  
09  (* CNat Definition *)
10  Class CNat A := {
11    O: A;
12    succ: A->A;
13    add: A->A->A;
14    add_comm: forall x y:A, add x y = add y x
15  }.
16  
17  (* O Commutativity Lemma *)
18  Lemma O_SO `{CNat}: add O (succ O) = add (succ O) O.
19  Proof.
20    apply add_comm.                 (* Class axiom *)
21  Qed.
```

That was CNat Class Definition and its O_SO Lemma. Now CInt Class Definition, some Notation and its invO_O Lemma that reuses CNat superclass axioms (add_comm axiom) and theorems (O_SO lemma):

```
24  (* -------------------------------------------------- *)
25  (* CInt Class *)
26  
27  
28  (* CInt Definition *)
29  Class CInt A `{CNat A} := {
30    inv: A->A;
31    add_inv: forall x:A, add x (inv x) = O
32  }.
33  
34  (* Some notation for convenience *)
35  Notation "´ x" := (succ x) (at level 25, right associativity).
36  Infix "±" := add (at level 50, left associativity).
37  Notation "¯ x" := (inv x) (at level 35, right associativity).
38  
39  (* O Additive Inverse Lemma *)
40  Lemma invO_O `{CInt}: (´O±O) ± ¯(O ±´O) = (´O±´´O) ± ¯(´´O ±´O).
41  Proof.
42    rewrite O_SO.                   (* Superclass Lemma *)
43    setoid_rewrite add_comm at 5.   (* Superclass Axiom *)
44    setoid_rewrite add_inv.         (* Class Axiom *)
45    reflexivity.
46  Qed.
```

As can be seen, Axioms and Theorems of superclasses can be used by subclasses. Also notation and setoid smart rewriting can be used to demostrate theorems in a beautifully formal, type-safe and extensible manner.

**PD**:

If you want to use `forall x:A` you need to parametrize your theorem with `Generalizable Variables`:

```
48 Generalizable Variables A.
49 (* Commutative Additive Inverse Lemma *)
50 Lemma inv_inv `{CInt A}: forall x:A, ¯x±x=O.
51 Proof.
52   setoid_rewrite add_comm.
53   apply add_inv.
54 Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You must show that your `CNat` is isomorphic with a subset of `CReal` and that the `CNat` operations are closed.

Here is an example that you may expand to your liking.  I prove a simple lemma using the `lra` tactic that is used for reals.

I use coercions so that I don't have to insert the injection functions `f` and `g` everywhere manually. They are there, but in invisible ink. Do `Set Printing Coercions.` if you want to see them.

```
Require Import Reals.

Open Scope R.
Parameter (N:Type)(f:N->R) (g:R->N).
Parameter iso1: forall x, f (g x) = x.
Parameter iso2: forall x, g (f x) = x.
Coercion f : N>->R.
Coercion g : R>->N.

Parameter (n0 n1 : N) (nplus nmult : N->N->N) .
Parameter nzero : n0 = 0.
Parameter none : n1 = 1.
Parameter nplus_ok : forall a b:N, nplus a b  = a+b.
Parameter nmult_ok : forall a b:N, nmult a b  = a*b.

Set Printing Coercions.
Print nplus_ok.
(*  nplus_ok : forall a b : N, nplus a b = g (f a + f b)  *)
Unset Printing Coercions.

(* useful tactic to rewrite N to R *)
Ltac NtoR :=
  rewrite ?nplus_ok,  ?nmult_ok, ?nzero, ?none,  ?iso1;
  try apply f_equal.

Require Import Psatz.
Goal forall (a b c:N),
    (nplus a (nplus b c)) + nmult 1 (a+n1+c) = nplus (2*nplus c a) (nplus (n0+1) b).
  intros.
  NtoR.
  lra.
Qed.
```

Comment: Here you are creating an isomorphism between Naturals and Reals, not between Naturals and a subset of Reals aren't you?

Comment: If you showed me how to do use a subset of instead of plain Reals this will be solved.

Comment: The `N` here is the intended "subset".

Comment: Mm but you are defining an isomorphism between Reals and that subset. That way if I were to prove something for Naturals or for that subset, I would be proving it also for Reals, which beats the purpose of Real inheritance I am aiming at.

Comment: Could you perhaps extend your question with one or two examples of what it is that you want to do that you are not currently able to do?

Comment: Two examples added.